# most used modules in drupal

Tags: drupal

What are the most used modules in Drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [this page](http://drupal.org/project/modules) and take a list of all modules sorted by installations. The most installed module over all drupal versions appears to be the Views module then, followed by CCK and token.

Answer (score 0):

[Content Construction Kit (CCK)](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) are probably used on most sites. Hard to think of any non-trivial site not using one or both. In fact CCK is now in Drupal 7 Core.

Answer (score 0):

CCK and views are the most used modules. All the modules list you can find at the [drupal site](http://drupal.org). If you want a list of all the SEO modules you can have a look at this [link](http://www.codeinsects.com/collection-of-seo-modules-for-drupal-6-and-drupal-7.html)